# NetBeans Xdebug path with MAMP issue

Tags: netbeans, mamp, xdebug

When I use NetBeans xdebug with my MAMP stack the url is messed up.

My MAMP PRO site is `testate.local:8888/path-to-code.php`. However when I debug with NetBeans the path is: `testate.local/path-to-code.php` so it breaks and won't debug.

I have been searching for a day and tested so many different things, php.ini, NetBeans preferences, MAMP PHP settings and I cannot find how to make it work.

Can anyone shed light on my issue?

Answer (score 0):

The short of it was Select the Project in Netbeans and right-click on it. Go to properties. Under Run configuration - update the Project URL. This adds the server port to the url.